# HTML 5 with IE9 / Drag and Drop

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am running a very simple example mentioned here

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp

Just to try Drag and Drop on IE 9.
I can see drag  but when I drag and drop a file on the area, IE simply renders the file rather then executing events .

please let me know if I need to change any config in IE

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is designed for you to drag and drop files. Rather, you can drag the w3school logo from the left box to the right box. If you're looking for drag and drop file, check http://html5demos.com/file-api/ for a demo

Comment: Thanks, I tried this link, i can open it but when I drag a file, again, IE opens the file rather then doing something else

Comment: i don't get it the example has

ev.preventDefault();

IE doesn't have preventDefault function.